# Finding average time on site using PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to work out average time on site, based on date and grouped by user id.

I'm not sure how to do this. I am using PostgreSQL

I imagine I would need to extract the time in seconds from one timestamp to the next, and then group by anonymous id to figure out how long a given user was on the site for.
Also, some users bounced, so they have only one timestamp logged
Can someone help?

Here is an example of the table, sorry I hope its workable!

```html
<style type="text/css">
    table.tableizer-table {
        font-size: 12px;
        border: 1px solid #CCC; 
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    } 
    .tableizer-table td {
        padding: 4px;
        margin: 3px;
        border: 1px solid #CCC;
    }
    .tableizer-table th {
        background-color: #104E8B; 
        color: #FFF;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>
<table class="tableizer-table">
<thead><tr class="tableizer-firstrow"><th>timestamp</th><th>page_id</th><th>anonymous_id</th><th>avg time on page per user</th></tr></thead><tbody>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:05:16</td><td>ajs-0181133c61e021cf8bc61dca99ad0dc2</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:04:47</td><td>ajs-8ab71732559a6906513eb4e38fa59365</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:03:53</td><td>ajs-838b5a6c202b19ebdc056bd10ea7731a</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:05:00</td><td>ajs-8a201f94ae9595ceed28809f4f2038f2</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:04:18</td><td>ajs-2993fb245759e2cf9088996319391c20</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:05:29</td><td>ajs-afe35c4ebd81e79da36185becf69b15c</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:04:35</td><td>ajs-86937a753cd8ba60320cdfb2d0460c0b</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:05:45</td><td>ajs-9aa528f73adb9cb8ce2aa6680f5fb9d5</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:04:39</td><td>ajs-f77bd802ff1f6ebe5dcf85b5e96893ff</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:06:02</td><td>ajs-520c36d229bcc8638ad8cf60cbc5181c</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:05:37</td><td>ajs-73e15b56359a2234cce6f274234095e5</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:06:10</td><td>ajs-444a6d7ad2d5551d92ba6361ed28e49d</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:05:49</td><td>ajs-5c9dc138f5bfc4a227ecdf00d382e058</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:04:31</td><td>ajs-ad6f34349f8ef20cc7ab3b00578b6d5e</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:03:41</td><td>ajs-a0cb6fbaf25c0fcd4ca506cc565f1b1a</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:04:35</td><td>ajs-e8f954ae61324e88512873220fdabd60</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:03:53</td><td>ajs-02c22b3daf97cb0665b7deed2406c356</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:04:43</td><td>ajs-290a09af5db1bf2fab8918bcee70171c</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:03:57</td><td>ajs-2cdf828d3a68b46fff756faf7893c5ce</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:05:33</td><td>ajs-ac6a02b7fd8bbaaa5f9409ffc3bd5f98</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:05:29</td><td>ajs-1a6b961327d8f5c875f7e358bcea5b57</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:03:57</td><td>ajs-dd1996712c14b898f6a8d39b6525d23b</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:05:33</td><td>ajs-e9898845bd37a9753703fffdf553abed</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:04:10</td><td>ajs-468ee2e2cb28204972b413579262fe13</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:04:02</td><td>ajs-fe96915adf5555c513052ed90b371aef</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:04:14</td><td>ajs-7a8643b62a951e81dc51c056553e1a79</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:04:06</td><td>ajs-38351d2cd5dc9999f1284beee2d71e7a</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:04:55</td><td>ajs-c2f653353d6a7bdd709c58051186d8be</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:04:22</td><td>ajs-94e7a05f741c017a910a925b16e535b2</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:05:08</td><td>ajs-6b872a8efa4398e32f33dfc13e4b55a2</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:05:00</td><td>ajs-0ecbcf08724cf3eede3d9554bd542639</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:05:08</td><td>ajs-5f2d73db40e671d482620298c86c0c8a</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:05:04</td><td>ajs-fc577bf16246fc2a58311dfdec2cd2f6</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:05:41</td><td>ajs-6d1593b0f4ed68d789ac5e8fcc1dd5ff</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:05:12</td><td>ajs-63cc5d110848b67eae11f5ec4fdf037f</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:03:45</td><td>ajs-02d7ee75096251d891af9c738d76a768</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:05:25</td><td>ajs-98b2d4eb3a2daa9020fe3196f6b30a3e</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:04:22</td><td>ajs-892589c4b2be6bf6f40924334d232c02</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:05:37</td><td>ajs-4d7ec764b6ee272d11e0a3fad4d9a89f</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:04:31</td><td>ajs-d8e5e582416b3468d7ec543011a38b78</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:05:41</td><td>ajs-eb6b65152f3b616ae8c0dc4e6da64b84</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:04:43</td><td>ajs-3bc3cf3235464c163e07b3f44c48555a</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:05:54</td><td>ajs-f3ca2c95b3f55fe76167fbb8a57eeb7b</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:04:51</td><td>ajs-6b270daed3c7bf790fcda3bfecb56e1d</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:03:38</td><td>ajs-3aba8042850b5430c4146921dd6e3e91</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:05:16</td><td>ajs-bf37fe9ef0281b031059b908a5601899</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:04:14</td><td>ajs-65a6183c3e65fe53e603e2b2a0cc4d2f</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:05:58</td><td>ajs-5ac611c27429cd30d824d61fe2f17b17</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:04:18</td><td>ajs-dc52469ae77c18ffa85e1c47861dd699</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:05:25</td><td>ajs-852c71b9d82e3f585e40bfb0f89e1681</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:04:27</td><td>ajs-4dd01a1c6a324622a20f011d6046cfd6</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:05:04</td><td>ajs-a67c2823652d67a13c643bdd04c4aa79</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:05:54</td><td>ajs-c3a0d4d0238bc4a6e4d37fe9e2bf2e63</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:04:27</td><td>ajs-e193485dff628bba36959a71e8dc552d</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:05:20</td><td>ajs-740559d24232423143b2c6410d519bad</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:03:45</td><td>ajs-3ea4f52a4181d3c921345078d0caefd3</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:04:39</td><td>ajs-b39df002d35c1232c559186e7bd1ef87</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:05:58</td><td>ajs-2ef724c1f25d3ba6c5a0f0428eadf436</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:04:02</td><td>ajs-8b465b89f740a2ce26f154f24e996022</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:04:47</td><td>ajs-2bee1c83d20292e9a324fc3f93f49ed8</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:06:02</td><td>ajs-b16e29ca124c76a4eb59bc2c837573c0</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:04:51</td><td>ajs-d6f80b6ac7a4503ca022687e1e62c6f1</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:06:06</td><td>ajs-bfdb8805c4e803034d310518b5db238f</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:04:55</td><td>ajs-ed47280371fece184d029c2e42a1a38b</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:06:06</td><td>ajs-a83e178e1dd5032babf239245a71f69a</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-29 06:05:12</td><td>ajs-123269af46e88c2e25cde7ea98567a97</td><td>003b4f15-d973-411b-9050-73fb2c37aba7</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-02-08 11:08:22</td><td>ajs-df8d23499d05b20a671ce3c95632740d</td><td>00596705-9c45-4726-bc9c-7ff7ca3c5d69</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-26 00:21:56</td><td>ajs-5c508e41f9d3130553e10777b24cc47e</td><td>005d2af2-34da-4531-b5b2-0eca95029e19</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-26 00:21:24</td><td>ajs-5ab7b2fc88b2ae3d34b2187b6cf8202d</td><td>005d2af2-34da-4531-b5b2-0eca95029e19</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-26 00:22:13</td><td>ajs-b3ff3ca7ad2971125a0c41c966512ab9</td><td>005d2af2-34da-4531-b5b2-0eca95029e19</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-26 00:21:28</td><td>ajs-c4bc375e277266ce1ccd7a37020f6289</td><td>005d2af2-34da-4531-b5b2-0eca95029e19</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-26 00:22:33</td><td>ajs-93f46395ae521cfc8e899138d9a78bcc</td><td>005d2af2-34da-4531-b5b2-0eca95029e19</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-26 00:21:40</td><td>ajs-bd1ac37182b2233e0d001b50987d3ebe</td><td>005d2af2-34da-4531-b5b2-0eca95029e19</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-26 00:22:13</td><td>ajs-06b8c4f6f835739620bc2c0fb0a997c9</td><td>005d2af2-34da-4531-b5b2-0eca95029e19</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-26 00:21:48</td><td>ajs-245ec86c2972e6b313299045ba555e46</td><td>005d2af2-34da-4531-b5b2-0eca95029e19</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-26 00:22:17</td><td>ajs-8c0e0888496a3fc6bafdd33395556a5e</td><td>005d2af2-34da-4531-b5b2-0eca95029e19</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-26 00:22:50</td><td>ajs-471843408960770b4d1abf04c69de875</td><td>005d2af2-34da-4531-b5b2-0eca95029e19</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-26 00:22:17</td><td>ajs-e85fc23666f1472859a9014fb0f5574e</td><td>005d2af2-34da-4531-b5b2-0eca95029e19</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-26 00:22:58</td><td>ajs-1cab0ce5eec6c3f3eb682f4a898252b9</td><td>005d2af2-34da-4531-b5b2-0eca95029e19</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-26 00:22:29</td><td>ajs-4c8b09e72e9c1a453bc34eea31e788a3</td><td>005d2af2-34da-4531-b5b2-0eca95029e19</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-26 00:21:24</td><td>ajs-96de775e0a36ae49fd55606530799b13</td><td>005d2af2-34da-4531-b5b2-0eca95029e19</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-26 00:22:41</td><td>ajs-dd7f624fdaf0f8ae009665917d287821</td><td>005d2af2-34da-4531-b5b2-0eca95029e19</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-26 00:21:36</td><td>ajs-249db228610d00492c5c1aa209581b56</td><td>005d2af2-34da-4531-b5b2-0eca95029e19</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-26 00:21:52</td><td>ajs-77d0576eaf88c51a35d61b23e45c0cc9</td><td>005d2af2-34da-4531-b5b2-0eca95029e19</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-26 00:21:44</td><td>ajs-a82c3093e251979a3f61f75907452070</td><td>005d2af2-34da-4531-b5b2-0eca95029e19</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-26 00:21:32</td><td>ajs-30c70195ae00fbca3d87274743fcb4e2</td><td>005d2af2-34da-4531-b5b2-0eca95029e19</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-26 00:22:09</td><td>ajs-53eccad3366af96e76ad9c0b1f5bb280</td><td>005d2af2-34da-4531-b5b2-0eca95029e19</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-26 00:22:00</td><td>ajs-b0a545a95b191cafaac5e45db27c7475</td><td>005d2af2-34da-4531-b5b2-0eca95029e19</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-26 00:22:25</td><td>ajs-72e45a0ef80305537705cf036b102684</td><td>005d2af2-34da-4531-b5b2-0eca95029e19</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-26 00:22:41</td><td>ajs-d78ef0aa430ad5138cb957065f6599e5</td><td>005d2af2-34da-4531-b5b2-0eca95029e19</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-26 00:22:33</td><td>ajs-4daeec0461571dc80705a4b893623c8f</td><td>005d2af2-34da-4531-b5b2-0eca95029e19</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-26 00:22:50</td><td>ajs-a997b202e10245222f0f0030c077c586</td><td>005d2af2-34da-4531-b5b2-0eca95029e19</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-26 00:23:02</td><td>ajs-31c9fd974d5238f05c543141766f6940</td><td>005d2af2-34da-4531-b5b2-0eca95029e19</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-26 00:22:54</td><td>ajs-9cbe252df2776d7cd44b8d025dddf1fe</td><td>005d2af2-34da-4531-b5b2-0eca95029e19</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-26 00:21:28</td><td>ajs-584ebd178f42860afcbd4f4bdb0844db</td><td>005d2af2-34da-4531-b5b2-0eca95029e19</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-26 00:21:44</td><td>ajs-216cd37936deee3b465a015753936777</td><td>005d2af2-34da-4531-b5b2-0eca95029e19</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-26 00:21:52</td><td>ajs-0bd3e21b7783b8f9398935c6bace55ea</td><td>005d2af2-34da-4531-b5b2-0eca95029e19</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-26 00:22:00</td><td>ajs-b143d807badc0b24013fbca77926fc3e</td><td>005d2af2-34da-4531-b5b2-0eca95029e19</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-26 00:21:56</td><td>ajs-fac043e194b137470bf7ee8a053e950c</td><td>005d2af2-34da-4531-b5b2-0eca95029e19</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-26 00:22:09</td><td>ajs-a1185d9bed79761bc2494d9cd8983799</td><td>005d2af2-34da-4531-b5b2-0eca95029e19</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-26 00:22:21</td><td>ajs-1dd3ed0e9946880a7cdd284d49ff12cb</td><td>005d2af2-34da-4531-b5b2-0eca95029e19</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-26 00:22:37</td><td>ajs-e2d075c082316e40472e55df20e468e0</td><td>005d2af2-34da-4531-b5b2-0eca95029e19</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-26 00:22:25</td><td>ajs-bed6479ff515be7b727703d0601c137f</td><td>005d2af2-34da-4531-b5b2-0eca95029e19</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-26 00:22:45</td><td>ajs-cb4e644884dc143ce85b93e72ca5e06e</td><td>005d2af2-34da-4531-b5b2-0eca95029e19</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-26 00:22:37</td><td>ajs-79f4786611d34a655129a9552d6dfa39</td><td>005d2af2-34da-4531-b5b2-0eca95029e19</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-26 00:22:45</td><td>ajs-9b4c3add6682b3ff5f44c1d91b1de6e0</td><td>005d2af2-34da-4531-b5b2-0eca95029e19</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-26 00:21:40</td><td>ajs-ac3b81d68c7ddb10872bf31f35e7eabe</td><td>005d2af2-34da-4531-b5b2-0eca95029e19</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-26 00:21:36</td><td>ajs-d0c9e5f2911fa97b2fed7f0d232694a6</td><td>005d2af2-34da-4531-b5b2-0eca95029e19</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-26 00:22:54</td><td>ajs-f8cd8f76a4dcdcab0340dbf1cdef33f4</td><td>005d2af2-34da-4531-b5b2-0eca95029e19</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-26 00:22:04</td><td>ajs-fd3b99b3dd6bf8901719d45ecd4a1113</td><td>005d2af2-34da-4531-b5b2-0eca95029e19</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-26 00:21:48</td><td>ajs-026b4c7cef6e3a7afc3bf5d5e16c851c</td><td>005d2af2-34da-4531-b5b2-0eca95029e19</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-26 00:23:02</td><td>ajs-ffe216ff902f77b433b36eba29bce3af</td><td>005d2af2-34da-4531-b5b2-0eca95029e19</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-26 00:23:06</td><td>ajs-12f783c721e856405833db54dd63160d</td><td>005d2af2-34da-4531-b5b2-0eca95029e19</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-26 00:22:04</td><td>ajs-b0c61cfdda7fd643744f409b8c4a212f</td><td>005d2af2-34da-4531-b5b2-0eca95029e19</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-26 00:21:32</td><td>ajs-26da8ab03d07c28c448c0b2f69dca410</td><td>005d2af2-34da-4531-b5b2-0eca95029e19</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-26 00:22:29</td><td>ajs-0aedf5807879078cd4ba29f2827f31e7</td><td>005d2af2-34da-4531-b5b2-0eca95029e19</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-26 00:22:21</td><td>ajs-b3e7aaad9a9673fd239e5668cb5a0eaf</td><td>005d2af2-34da-4531-b5b2-0eca95029e19</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-26 00:23:06</td><td>ajs-783c41ff7e4fb5348dabba7706353369</td><td>005d2af2-34da-4531-b5b2-0eca95029e19</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-26 00:22:58</td><td>ajs-f665f96c9cbe2f1ecafd328b0c96c83f</td><td>005d2af2-34da-4531-b5b2-0eca95029e19</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-05-12 12:11:50</td><td>ajs-e565c90c8f86ab4b4686c16a18546f14</td><td>005eaec6-dbc2-4ea7-8da7-59647e949aee</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-05-12 12:11:50</td><td>ajs-ee6482c6aec1df0fc438cb2bf00f7821</td><td>005eaec6-dbc2-4ea7-8da7-59647e949aee</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-05-07 12:36:18</td><td>ajs-a7038e3e91d8003bcc485f0181083213</td><td>005f710b-3100-4606-b515-6ecd8b35330a</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-25 09:47:02</td><td>ajs-0e5f88b4a8897a0ed5ddaaf2e683b35f</td><td>006d3b23-1d7b-4af6-a202-7a104e7a4928</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-25 09:47:02</td><td>ajs-e69c54da613f6e65d74ee47bc2df70cc</td><td>006d3b23-1d7b-4af6-a202-7a104e7a4928</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-05-07 11:52:32</td><td>ajs-150ebc5b8d4c438c54112567c2225545</td><td>006febe7-0146-4fbb-a74e-4ed9490b880d</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-05-07 11:52:32</td><td>ajs-b9a4d19cbbba931eb09188b2cd410d96</td><td>006febe7-0146-4fbb-a74e-4ed9490b880d</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-31 10:49:49</td><td>ajs-ca6fbb4ad7280589475580cf787c9371</td><td>0097549a-ab4a-4429-b126-9b3417615948</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-31 10:49:56</td><td>ajs-155dddee29735ef4f077af9cac78b87c</td><td>0097549a-ab4a-4429-b126-9b3417615948</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-04-13 05:37:20</td><td>ajs-7f36140d7e142d02ef7809ba16630a04</td><td>0097549a-ab4a-4429-b126-9b3417615948</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-31 10:51:20</td><td>ajs-f4322a946259058b0b5e8145afe17285</td><td>0097549a-ab4a-4429-b126-9b3417615948</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-04-13 05:38:30</td><td>ajs-4acc9c15c55633a18ea1aff4ea28ab2c</td><td>0097549a-ab4a-4429-b126-9b3417615948</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-04-13 05:34:49</td><td>ajs-9ba1c3ed2aff4ab12fe1eec62820bb99</td><td>0097549a-ab4a-4429-b126-9b3417615948</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-04-15 00:51:05</td><td>ajs-2b3f059f3c4a5840e1e6dada26227e8f</td><td>0097549a-ab4a-4429-b126-9b3417615948</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-04-13 05:38:28</td><td>ajs-9660ec50d8f8005c75b5faeb0e41e7db</td><td>0097549a-ab4a-4429-b126-9b3417615948</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-31 10:50:12</td><td>ajs-91040aeee13ff5d711c990ad44d3bc3b</td><td>0097549a-ab4a-4429-b126-9b3417615948</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-04-15 01:12:01</td><td>ajs-c659b1d00596210050d60b8687a4343a</td><td>0097549a-ab4a-4429-b126-9b3417615948</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-04-13 06:20:37</td><td>ajs-d5ad2f9fb984b659f7b40d0c461aa699</td><td>0097549a-ab4a-4429-b126-9b3417615948</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-31 10:48:13</td><td>ajs-800ef6410a388486e8775ab2a461e24b</td><td>0097549a-ab4a-4429-b126-9b3417615948</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-04-13 05:33:29</td><td>ajs-dce18874b336845d4f708b40555e8400</td><td>0097549a-ab4a-4429-b126-9b3417615948</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-31 10:50:14</td><td>ajs-ef257d5cb2ea61a6a189642ef489508b</td><td>0097549a-ab4a-4429-b126-9b3417615948</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-04-13 06:20:34</td><td>ajs-a1d586c1d32cdd4adef7de52fc4f776a</td><td>0097549a-ab4a-4429-b126-9b3417615948</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-04-13 05:36:56</td><td>ajs-94fa763f80ed2d728c16765256f396e9</td><td>0097549a-ab4a-4429-b126-9b3417615948</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-31 10:50:16</td><td>ajs-945817ef6978192dccbce3eb4090c6b6</td><td>0097549a-ab4a-4429-b126-9b3417615948</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-04-13 05:38:26</td><td>ajs-f65f167663e23fa37e0a137c027f0e8a</td><td>0097549a-ab4a-4429-b126-9b3417615948</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-03-31 10:51:24</td><td>ajs-6a786e0e034ed8d9125796179149d6ab</td><td>0097549a-ab4a-4429-b126-9b3417615948</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-04-15 00:50:50</td><td>ajs-4712cc315c420b46cd64d6fb4ab802e2</td><td>0097549a-ab4a-4429-b126-9b3417615948</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-04-13 06:20:36</td><td>ajs-4c66ea227eb8665e3f1c67c900d0a027</td><td>0097549a-ab4a-4429-b126-9b3417615948</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-04-13 05:37:01</td><td>ajs-ee689741b1e2c454ecd8c30850ec601d</td><td>0097549a-ab4a-4429-b126-9b3417615948</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-04-15 01:12:25</td><td>ajs-525d8d23734227968e70e2fa8e76a747</td><td>0097549a-ab4a-4429-b126-9b3417615948</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-04-15 01:12:14</td><td>ajs-9bce0fac158c3b72e31d97da90d1ceeb</td><td>0097549a-ab4a-4429-b126-9b3417615948</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-04-15 01:12:19</td><td>ajs-5f154c7af22b72824b8ccee3d86e2c60</td><td>0097549a-ab4a-4429-b126-9b3417615948</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-04-15 01:12:32</td><td>ajs-f04ac3c3d2b1ec7d2f781a45a7fce4d2</td><td>0097549a-ab4a-4429-b126-9b3417615948</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2021-05-05 14:43:01</td><td>ajs-f66b9a88a0b605bb8f8452c7d3cddd42</td><td>009c4eff-17a4-42b1-8d54-e0ed85208c50</td><td></td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: Don't try to reinvent the wheel: there are tools that do these kind of analysis for you (such as google analytics IIRC).

Comment: Thank you @NirAlfasi I do know this, but I have to do it this way unfortunately.

Comment: Push back! I've seen it happen too many times... You end up having to maintain a poor logic that becomes very complex and doesn't do the job like existing tools and from there it's only going down-hill... If that's not the core of your product (doing analytics on a website) you should push back strongly!

Comment: Please do not link to some external files for sample data. **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add the sample data as formatted text. And please also include the expected output.  See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables.